# Multiple vertical panels in OpenGL window

Tags: opengl

Is it possible in OpenGL to separate the window into multiple vertical "panels" such that each displays a different set of shapes?

I would want to synchronize the horizontal axes across those panels, but the vertical axes would be completely independent (location as well as scale).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is to apply multiple calls to `glViewport()`.  You have to render each vertical strip in turn and then set the viewport to render to the next vertical strip and repeat.  I do this to split the screen in half and render a scene from two different viewpoints, but there's no reason that you should have to render the same scene in the second or n-th viewport.

So my {edited} code looks something like this:

```
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
...
// Draw the left scene
glViewport(0,0,halfWidth,fullHeight);
glScissor(0,0,halfWidth,fullHeight);
glClear(...);
glPushMatrix();
setLeftEyeModelView();
renderScene();
glPopMatrix();

// Draw the right scene
glViewport(halfWidth,0,halfWidth,fullHeight);
glScissor(halfWidth,0,halfWidth,fullHeight);
glClear(...);
glPushMatrix();
setRightEyeModelView();
renderScene();
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: This requires some additional `glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST); glScissor(...);` matching the viewport, otherwise strange rendering artifacts may show up.

Comment: @datenwolf I believe you, but I've never had any problems without using it myself.  Under what conditions do the artifacts show up?  A quick search makes it look like `glClear()` is applied to the whole screen, rather than the viewport unless you use the scissor test, but I actually count on that.

Comment: The issues are mostly related to clipping; under some circumstances a primitive doesn't get clipped on the viewport edge, causing the primitive to overdraw into the region outside the viewport. OpenGL doesn't explicitly define the correct behaviour, so proper clipping and overdraw can be observed in different implementations. However if scissor testing is enabled to proper behaviour is enforced. The same goes for adding clip planes that match the clip space boundaris that is, because viewport clipping is implemented in screen space, whereas clip planes operate in eye space.